# Is there a conditional operator without the else part in Java?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I know that that you can use something like this in Java:

```
(a > b) ? a : b;
```

Is there something similar just without the else part?

Comment: ..the `else` part is optional, no?

Comment: What would the value be then if the expression is false?

Comment: without `else` then just do `if(a > b) z = a`. I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an expression, not a statement, which means it always evaluates to something. If there wasn't an "else part" there would be nothing for the expression to evaluate to if the test was false. So, no, there's nothing similar without the else.

The thing I like about using the [conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) is that you can assign something like

```
foo =  a > b ? c : d;
```

and reading it you know foo got something assigned to it, regardless of whether the test was true. So it provides you with a way to indicate that a value is assigned that depends on some test.

Groovy has some similar operators:

`?:`, the Elvis operator, assigns the value on the right as a default if the expression on the left is null.

`?.`, the safe-null operator, evaluates to null if the left side evaluates to null. This is handy for cases where you have a chain of possibly-null things, like `foo?.bar?.baz`, where you would rather not blow up with an NPE if something is null but would rather not type out all the null checks.

Comment: Darn, beat me by 24 seconds.

Comment: simply explained

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't. It wouldn't make sense.

`?:` is the ternary comparison operator - an expression. If there was no else statement, what would the value of the expression be? C# has a shorthand version `??` but that's just syntactical sugar and Java doesn't have anything like that anyway.

Comment: It is called _ternary_ operator. (Sorry, could not improve your answer because of six letters restriction for edits.)

Comment: @nutlike: technically the jls calls it the conditional operator. which i didn't know until i googled it just now.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes: Thanks for your comment (and the link inside your answer) - did not know this either. For the sake of completeness: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Comment: @nutlike Oops, I don't know what I was thinking with "trinary". Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you're using it to assign a value to a var, which I'll call "c", and the idea is you only want to assign the value when the if statement is true.  The normal way would be:

```
if(a > b) c = a;
```

But if you *really* want to use the ternary syntax you could write:

```
c = a > b ? a : c;
```

Note that the ternary parens are optional so I've omitted them.